# Polymer Repeat in Object array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, polymer

I am facing issue with similar Data array where I need to get the FieldName with checkbox but after time multiple options I am unable to get the FieldName with Polymer repeat.

[image]

I am currently using

```
<template repeat="{{ FieldName, i in ReportFieldDetail }}">
   <template repeat="{{ value, j in FieldName }}">
     {{ i }}:{{ j }}. {{ value }}
    </template>
</template>
```

But unable to get any result.

Comment: I am correcting my code which I am using however its not giving any result    </template> -->
           <template repeat="{{ FieldName, i in ReportFieldDetail }}">
             <template repeat="{{ value, j in FieldName }}">
               {{ i }}:{{ j }}. {{ value }}
             </template>
           </template>

Comment: You are edit your question not in comment.

Comment: Do you need any information on the question, please let me know..

Comment: @user2640679 what is the variable `i`?

Comment: variable i is temp variable...